# Javascript "EventSource" in C# .NET 5.0

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, .net-5, eventsource

my company choose "Mercure" (https://mercure.rocks/docs/getting-started) to manage Server-Sent Events.
We install "Mercure HUB" on a server and now, in C# .NET 5.0, I must implement the server-side (publisher, that I already implemented) and the client-side (subscriber).
The subscriber must be done with a WPF

From the "getting-started" page I can see a Javascript example that I need to transform into C#
I don't know how to manage a "EventSource" in C#
Any ideas ?

```
// The subscriber subscribes to updates for the https://example.com/users/dunglas topic
// and to any topic matching https://example.com/books/{id}
const url = new URL('https://localhost/.well-known/mercure');
url.searchParams.append('topic', 'https://example.com/books/{id}');
url.searchParams.append('topic', 'https://example.com/users/dunglas');
// The URL class is a convenient way to generate URLs such as https://localhost/.well-known/mercure?topic=https://example.com/books/{id}&topic=https://example.com/users/dunglas
const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
// The callback will be called every time an update is published
eventSource.onmessage = e => console.log(e); // do something with the payload
```

Comment: You mean you want a C# client to listen for events instead of a browser client? Or is this because you're using Blazor? Or what? Your explanation lacks context, and also it's unclear what, if any, effort you have put into this yourself. e.g. https://makolyte.com/event-driven-dotnet-how-to-consume-an-sse-endpoint-with-httpclient/ looks interesting. Did you search for anything?

Comment: Thanks, I added some information into the original post.
I made some research and tried to make some GetAsync to subscribe to some events and now i tried your suggestion but nothing works.
When i made this async call, seems that the WPF page is stuck in the loop of the call and i can't do anything else

Comment: Right so this is WPF...that helps us a bit. But you need to show us the code you've tried, so we can understand where the problem might be. Possibly you need to offload the job of listening for events to a background worker task, for example.

Comment: My fault, i manage a new Thread and now your suggestion works !
Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. If you solved it, please add your code solution below, with a brief explanation, for the benefit of others (and for your benefit too, if it attracts upvotes) - thanks. This site is far more useful when the questions also have answers attached!

Answer (score 1):

The code of this page works (https://makolyte.com/event-driven-dotnet-how-to-consume-an-sse-endpoint-with-httpclient/)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    string stockSymbol = "VTSAX";
    string url = $"http://localhost:9000/stockpriceupdates/{stockSymbol}";

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Establishing connection");
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync(url)))
            {
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var message = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received price update: {message}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Here you can check for 
            //specific types of errors before continuing
            //Since this is a simple example, i'm always going to retry
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("Retrying in 5 seconds");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
}
```